# The filter in Acumatica does not follow row-level Security

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

please help me :(

Pricecode field in the Sale-price-worksheet (AR202010) screen in acumatica. When I select priceType = customer, the pricecode shows all customers and does not follow the Row-Level Security that I have installed.

I have viewed some customer fields on another screen, but the filter is still correct.

Sorry I'm not good at English,I hope everyone understands what I'm talking. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug in Acumatica and I would suggest opening a case about this issue so they can fix this in a future release. In the mean time, you can create a PXGraphExtension of ARPriceWorksheetMaint and override the CustomerCode view to add the Customer group restrictions.

```
public class ARPriceWorksheetMaintExtension : PXGraphExtension<ARPriceWorksheetMaint>
{

    #region Views

    public PXSelectJoin<BAccount,
                                    InnerJoin<Customer, On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<BAccount.bAccountID>>>,
                                    Where2<
                                            Where<Match<Customer, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>,
                                            And<
                                                Where<BAccount.type, Equal<BAccountType.customerType>,
                                                    Or<BAccount.type, Equal<BAccountType.combinedType>>>>>> customerCode;

    #endregion

}
```

In the code snippet, I made a customerCode code view (with a lowercase c) which will override Acumatica's CustomerCode view. In my view, I added an Inner Join to Customer so I can Add the Match<> on Customer which will apply group restrictions to the select. This will change the query of selector attribute because in ARPriceWorksheetMaint Acumatica overrides the ExecuteSelect method to change the BQL to use the BQL of the CustomerCode view.